# How do I get a div to grab it's background image from the internet instead of from the cache?

Tags: javascript, html

Relevant Javascript being run once every fifteen minutes to get the relevant image off the internet:

```
document.getElementById('weatherbug').style.background = "url('http://tinyurl.com/jwltx5s') repeat scroll -1px -24px transparent";
```

Relevant HTML this is linked to:

```
<DIV ID='weatherbug'></DIV>
```

Other HTML I've used to try and keep this from using the cache:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-directive: no-cache">
```

Results:  The image refreshes itself from the cache regardless, ignoring changes in the source image, which changes roughly once per hour.  If there is not internet access, this results in a blank image (good behavior) unless there's a copy in cache, in which case an old image is shown (bad behavior).  Also, if there is a copy in the cache, the newly updated image on the internet is not shown (bad behavior).

Other tricks I have tried:  I've attempted to alter my javascript to add a randomizing element on the back end of the address, to force the cache's contents to be invalidated with each invocation, but altering the address by adding a ?randomnumberherebasedofftheDateObject on the ass end of the address breaks both the original link to the image and the tinyurl version since neither end in a proper .gif suffix.

How can I force the cache to NOT save this image, or at least to invalidate it after a decent time interval so a new download from the relevant server is required to display the information?  Frankly I'm stumped. :(

- Aaron Nichols

Comment: I want this to be as cross-compatible as possible, and I do not want to change global browser settings on a one-by-one basis in order to get the result.  This should be entirely within the scope of my HTML and/or Javascript.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a real answer, but you could try appending a unique id to the image URI that is regenerated on each request.

Comment: @winterblood: I did just that, as mentioned in the 'other tricks I have tried' section.  It breaks the URL when attempted, and is a no-go for this particular image file.  Sorry.

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't see that in my haste.

Comment: Guessing a little bit into the blue here: Try to add a "must-revalidate" parameter to the CONTENT attribute of your Cache-Control header. I've read some articles about similar problems just today and this is something I stumbled upon by accident: "must-revalidate" forces the browser on each load to check if the copy in the cache is still identical to the original source on the server. If the original source has changed, the browser should update the copy in it's cache.

Comment: @VoodooDS: I didn't know about that parameter...I'm giving it a try now.  If successful, I will definitely give you credit for the help.  Thank you.

Comment: The headers can possibly be ignored.

Comment: Test concluded.  The altered Cache-Control header is ineffective in solving the misbehavior issues already noted.  @Jasen: You were correct...they are being ignored by my browser, even though they do show up in the page info when such is examined.

Comment: So far the only way to get the image in question to reload from the source is to manually refresh the page, which is a rather extreme solution which would make use of the page as a whole a problem if it was put into my cycling update function.  Any other ideas for making this image non-cachable or forced to revalidate in a way the browser will not ignore?

Comment: If you are willing to give up the shortened URL then you can use the appended cache-buster/random number.

Comment: @Jasen: As describe in the original post, the appended cache-buster solution does not work, either for the tiny-url version or the original longer version, given neither have an ending that is friendly to using ?foorandomnumberhere manipulation.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid hitting tinyurl? My answer below clearly wouldn't work because the request just redirects to the same end url which doesn't change. Why not just hit the url directly? http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/cgi-bin/banner/ban/wxBanner?bannertype=wu_simplewhite&airportcode=KTTN&ForcedCity=Princeton&ForcedState=NJ&zip=08540&language=EN

Comment: @Geuis: Doesn't matter, I tried applying cache-busting to both the full version and the tinyurl version.  Those were attempts 1 and 2 before I went on to meta tags, asking on here, then meta tags again (with VoodooDS's must-revalidate option), and now I'm spinning my wheels, trying such longshots as constant opacity modification to trick the browser into redownloading from source material.  Probably won't work, but if it does I'll answer my own question and put a big question mark on why that method actually works.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a demo site I could look at? Might be able to do this by grabbing the image via a xhr request then displaying it as data uri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where your difficulties are. Cache busting is the way to go.

The first thing is you shouldn't be using the url shortener. Just access the end url directly.

All you need to do is add a cache busting parameter and a random value to the end of each url request.

I've setup a codepen that demonstrates this. It gets the updated image every 2 seconds. Monitor the image requests in dev tools and you can see the images are not being cached.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EayVJO

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var url = 'http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/cgi-bin/banner/ban/wxBanner?bannertype=wu_simplewhite&airportcode=KTTN&ForcedCity=Princeton&ForcedState=NJ&zip=08540&language=EN';

  var weatherbug = document.querySelector('#weatherbug');
  setInterval(function () {
    var rand = Math.floor(Date.now() * Math.random());
    weatherbug.style.background = 'url(' + url + '&qqq=' + rand + ') center center no-repeat';
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Repeating from above...  Other tricks I have tried: I've attempted to alter my javascript to add a randomizing element on the back end of the address, to force the cache's contents to be invalidated with each invocation, but altering the address by adding a ?randomnumberherebasedofftheDateObject on the ass end of the address breaks both the original link to the image and the tinyurl version since neither end in a proper .gif suffix.

Comment: Ergo: The remote server doesn't ignore the meaningless parameter, and instead of the expected image file, I get a similar one that either lacks all of the data that the original shows (and updates once per hour), or simply throws a 404 error at me as in your exact example.  Thank you, but I tried this trick before I tried the META tags (which also failed).  Is there another method that could be useful here?

Comment: Commenting on your edited answer: Again, I tried this method (albeit with a slightly different implementation) and I came up with either a corrupted image file (the 'meaningless parameter' was not dropped by the remote server and caused me to get screwed up data) or it would just give up on a 404.  Go ahead and try the following links and you will see precisely what I mean.  This approach is not valid for this application.

Comment: What links? None in your comment.

Comment: Link 1 (works but is subject to caching issues): http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/cgi-bin/banner/ban/wxBanner?bannertype=wu_simplewhite&airportcode=KTTN&ForcedCity=Princeton&ForcedState=NJ&zip=08540&language=EN

Comment: Link 4 (corrupted - weather information truncated due to an unreadable language reference at the tail end of the URL): http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/cgi-bin/banner/ban/wxBanner?bannertype=wu_simplewhite&airportcode=KTTN&ForcedCity=Princeton&ForcedState=NJ&zip=08540&language=EN?foo

Comment: Ergo this method cannot and will not work in this application.  Cache-busting by adding ?xyzzyrandomnumbersfoo only confuses the server involved that tries to parse EN?xyzzyrandomnumbersfoo as a language, fails, and in return throws back a corrupted image file (no language to write in to tell you that it's overcast, raining, what have you).  Sorry, but this fails...as does META header manipulation.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvbgoa fix -- it works and does not cache. The random needs to be in the setInterval loop like in the code above. @AaronNichols check your query string parameters, what's happening here is not `?somerandom` but `&qqq=somerandom` where qqq is a key not recognized by the server on that url.

Comment: That is a good point, and I just tested it.  This is a valid method of cache-breaking the image.  Thank you.

Comment: Aaron, I don't want to sound rude. But I don't think you're actually looking at the example I provided in the codepen or understanding what I've been saying. Your Link 3 is something I already said not to do. Link 4 is *not* an example of what I said will work. You don't simply add '?foo', especially since the search params are already defined (there's already a '?' in the url). If you add '&foo=123456' it will work just fine. Try it again.

Comment: My apologies, I thought this was yet another ?foobreakerattempt.  I should have read the code more closely.  That would not work, but the &qqq=foobreakerattempt DOES work.  Thank you.